# C# Attempted to read or writer protected memory

Tags: c#, multithreading

I write down a class to record results to xml files.When this multi-threads debug,it's get "attempt to read or write protected memory..." error.Why does the error display?

```
    static private readonly object recordLock = new object();
    private readonly object createLock = new object();

    public static XMLHandle GetXMLHandle()
    {
        if (xmlHandle == null)
        {
            lock (lockHelper)
            {
                if (xmlHandle == null)
                    xmlHandle = new XMLHandle();
            }
        }
        return xmlHandle;
    }
    public void RecordXML(string filePath, string fileName, string content, bool HaveLink)
    {
        System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(recordLock);<<======here
        //...
        System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(recordLock);
    }
```

Comment: This [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8789ea67-fbc5-4a7b-a4eb-d4a8a050d5c1/attempt-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indicating-that-other-memory-is-corrupt?forum=vbpowerpacks) link might help

Comment: This line does not give error. I think there is some other issue.

Comment: What's throwing it - Visual Studio, debugger or your process? Do you have a stack trace or any other data from the exception?

Comment: Protip: You should always use `try...finally` with such constructs to make sure you don't get a stuck lock. Or even better, use the built-in `lock(...) { }` syntax which was made for this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

May be an invalid code generated by xml serializer?

Also VS debugger sometimes crashes on multithread debugging and you can do only few things to workaround it.

1. Ensure that you are not debugging an optimized binary (in Project Properties - Build - Optimize code).
2. Try switching between 32-64 bit.
3. Try toggling "Enable native code debugging".
4. Try toggling "Enable VS hosting process". I encountered a debugger problem myself and this fixed it.
5. Try switching between .NET frameworks (especially 3.5 and 4.0+).
6. Update your Visual Studio.

3 and 4 are located in the Debug tab of Project Properties.

Comment: @E.Tarrent this is just a list of things which may remove some debugger problems but noone knows what's exactly going on in your particular case.